# what are these white hard 'bubble' spots on the branches of my 18+ year old Weeping Japanese Maple?

Tags: identification, japanese-maple

[image][image][image]

What are these hard white 'bubbles' on the branches of my 18+ year old Weeping Japanese  Maple tree??

Answer (score 1):

Those are a type of scale I believe.  Scrape them off with a twig, then spray the tree with a Dawn/water mix.  Do you notice ants on the tree as well, feeding off their honeydew?

You can also add some rubbing alcohol to the mixture to penetrate the waxy bodies of the scale.